# Regular expression match when specific digits AND words appear

Tags: python, regex, string, verification

I am quite new to regex, working on string verification where I want both conditions to be met. I am matching text containing 7digit numbers starting with 4 or 7 + string needs to contain one of the provided words.

What I managed so far:

```
\b((4|7)\d{6})\b|(\border|Order|Bestellung|bestellung|commande|Commande|ordine|Ordine|objednavku|Objednavku|objednavka|Objednavka)
```

Regex above correctly finds numbers but words are after OR statement which I would need to follow AND logic instead.

Could you please help me implement a change that would work as AND statement between digits and words?

Comment: Try remove the `|` before `(\border....`

Comment: Something like https://regex101.com/r/fArlqK/2 ?

Comment: @SeaBean Already tried removing | but it did not match anything.

WiktorStribiżew - Thank you very much Sir, this actually works!

Comment: `^[47]\d{6}(?:[Oo]rder|[Bb]estellung|[Cc]ommande|[Oo]rdine|[Oo]bjednavku|[oO]bjednavka)`

Comment: @VishalSingh Thank you for upper/lower case implementation!

Comment: Sorry, a bit confused.  Do we need to match for the string e.g.  `4123456 Order` ?  If so, @WiktorStribiżew's  sample seems doesn't match the word part.  Just curious.  Wiktor's solutions are always excellent, but this time I don't understand.

Comment: I am currently deep testing it but it seems to work as expected. Basically just match only if string contains both 7long digits starting 4|7 but the string also needs to contain one of the words provided in regex.

Comment: See [this](https://regex101.com/r/1zQD1X/1) using the regex by @WiktorStribiżew and added 2 test strings.  The word parts are not included in the "Match Information" in either Match part or Group 1 on the right hand side.  So, if we want to extract also the word part, it can't do ?

Comment: @SeaBean Yes, it actually does not recognize keywords when after the number. Issue I see as well is that my string is basically an email body where I can have some blank lines between the text. From what I see, it doesnt match in that case either.

Comment: Could you simply see my answer below and provide feeback where appropriate? My pattern does what you need: multiline aware and captures the number. If you want any more functionality, simply drop a comment below the *answer*.

Comment: My apologies @WiktorStribiżew, I am getting a bit lost in all the provided options. Will deep test them all and come back.

Comment: When I say "something like", it is not a final solution suggestion, it is a way to see if this approach is what you need. With regex, there are a lot of ways to match strings, that is why I suggested "something" and the answer provides a precised solution with explanation. Please make sure you understand what the solution does, then test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```regex
(?s)^(?=.*\b(?:order|Order|Bestellung|bestellung|commande|Commande|ordine|Ordine|objednavku|Objednavku|objednavka|Objednavka)\b).*\b([47]\d{6})\b
```

If you can and want use a case insensitive matching with `re.I`, you can use

```r
(?si)^(?=.*\b(?:order|bestellung|commande|ordine|objednavk[ua])\b).*\b([47]\d{6})\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fArlqK/4).

This matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*\b(?:order|Order|Bestellung|bestellung|commande|Commande|ordine|Ordine|objednavku|Objednavku|objednavka|Objednavka)\b)` - a positive lookahead that matches any zero or more chars, as many as possible, up to any of the whole words listed in the group
- `.*` - zero or more chars, as many as possible
- `\b([47]\d{6})\b` - a 7-digit number as  a whole word that starts with `4` or `7`.

Do not forget to use a raw string literal to define a regex in Python code:

```py
pattern = r'(?si)^(?=.*\b(?:order|bestellung|commande|ordine|objednavk[ua])\b).*\b([47]\d{6})\b'
```

Comment: Hi Wiktor, after proper testing, your regex above is the ultimate working solution. Thank you very much also for the breakdown explanation. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

By default, everything in regex is AND
if you do
abc,
it means "a" AND "b" AND "c"
so there is no need for an AND in regex

just remove the | between the numbers match and the words

```
\b(4|7)\d{6}(border|Order|Bestellung|bestellung|commande|Commande|ordine|Ordine|objednavku|Objednavku|objednavka|Objednavka)\b
```

I assume the backslash with the first word \border was a mistake.
This can match stuff like : "4958374border"

Comment: Thank you for explanation regarding AND implementation. Though, the code provided does not match but thats ok, what worked for me was as posted by @Wiktor

Comment: This is a wrong pattern because it does not match what you need, it matches a 7-digit number that is glued to the words in the group, and instead of `order`, now, this pattern requires `border`.